# compare two columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I know I just asked a question, but I realized I asked it all wrong

So in MYSQL if you I a two tables one with an SSN column and another with a CSSN column, both integers, how can I determine which SSN's are NOT in the CSSN column?

Comment: First of all, I would go back and go back and choose an accepted answer if it answered your *wrong* question correctly, per proper Stack Overflow etiquette.  Second of all, keep in mind you may have duplicates (if you are storing last 4).  Third of all, I don't like storing private information without some sort of proper hashing that relies on a salt.  This is all assuming SSN is the acronym for Social Security Number.

Comment: No sorry I messed up and asked the wrong question... I did however check the best answer for both of the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple query should do it:

```
select SSN from table1 where
       SSN not in (select CSSN from table2)
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d89f7/1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 t1 INNER JOIN tab2 t2
ON t1.SSN <> t2.CSSN
```